# How to display/process a SpringBoot API response in React.js (validation)?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

I have a function that's written in spring boot backend application. The function looks like this:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> signUpforActivity(@RequestBody ActivitySignUp activitySignUp) {
        try {
            List<Account_Activity> accountActivities = this.activityService.accountActivities(activitySignUp.getActivityId());
            Optional<Activity> activity = this.activityService.getActivity(String.valueOf(activitySignUp.getActivityId()));
            if(accountActivities.size() < activity.get().getMaxParticipants()) {
                this.activityService.signUp(activitySignUp, true);
                return new ResponseEntity<>("Sign up for activity successful", HttpStatus.OK);
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Maximaal aantal deelnemers is bereikt.", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Something went wrong", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

I would like to process/display the messages written inside of the ResponseEntity's.
I just do not know how.

This is the code where the fetching of this function happens (But the fetch doesn't get processed yet):

```
 Signup(activitySignUp: ActivitySignUp) {
    const body = JSON.stringify(activitySignUp);
    const options = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    };
    return this.http.post<any>(this.source + '/signup', body, options)
  }
```

This is where the fetch gets processed:

```
signUp() {
    this.signUpOff.activityId = this.activity.id;
    console.log('signup');
    console.log(this.fid);
    this.signUpOff.fid = this.fid;
    this.service.Signup(this.signUpOff).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      alert(data);
    });
    this.router.navigate(['/ownActivity']);
  }
```

How can i tell my react app to display the ResponseEntity messages? so i think i have to check if the httpstatus is OK, then display the ""Sign up for activity successful"" message. If the httpstatus is not ok (bad request) then display "Maximaal aantal deelnemers is bereikt" message.

Any ideas?